# Error while doing rake db:setup in Grape APi sample code

Tags: ruby, api, rest, grape-api

Here is the error on typing `rake db:setup`

```
git://github.com/leftbee/em-postgresql-adapter.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

So i tried to run bundle install but after that still getting this error.
I'm following this getting started post

```
https://github.com/djones/grape-goliath-example
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `bundle exec rake db:setup` instead.